# Javascript - onclick function change boolean value and change attr visibility

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, conditional-statements

So I'm learning Javascript and I have a doubt on changing a global variable with boolean variable, while changing the attr of visibility on an element.

The code is this:

```
var lastView=false;

$("#idShipmentActionsCombo-icon").on('click', function(){

if (lastview=false){

$('#idShipmentActionsCombo-lb').attr('style', 'visibility: visible');
    lastView=true;

}

else if(lastView=true){

$('#idShipmentActionsCombo-lb').attr('style', 'visibility: hidden');
    lastView===false;

    }
}
```

So `#idShipmentActionsCombo-icon` is the element I click in, `#idShipmentActionsCombo-lb` and this is what I want to show and hide depending on the value of lastView.

Thanks in advance, and I apologize for my English since it's not my main language.

Answer (score 1):

Since you use jQuery use `.toggle()` method instead of booleans, conditions and style.

```
$("#idShipmentActionsCombo-icon").on('click', function(){ 
   $('#idShipmentActionsCombo-lb').toggle();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing a closing `);` at the very end from your `.on(` In addition, there are a few cases where "===" and "=" are confused and where capitalization is incorrect. See this: http://jsfiddle.net/215sxj90/3/

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you're confusing assignment with logical operators.
The following is the assignment:

```
lastView = true;
```

and the following is the logical operator - comparison:

```
lastView === true
```

The latter should be used in your conditional statements - `if`, `else if` etc.:

```
var lastView = false;

$("#idShipmentActionsCombo-icon").on('click', function () {

    if (lastview === false) {

        $('#idShipmentActionsCombo-lb').attr('style', 'visibility: visible');
        lastView = true;

    }
    else if (lastView === true) {
        $('#idShipmentActionsCombo-lb').attr('style', 'visibility: hidden');
        lastView = false;

    }
}
```